# How to avoid using null?

Tags: scala

Suppose, I have my domain object named **"Office"**:

```
case class Office(
   id: Long,
   name: String,
   phone: String,
   address: String
) {
    def this(name: String, phone: String, address: String) = this(
        null.asInstanceOf[Long], name, phone, address
    )
}
```

When I create new **Office**:

```
new Office("officeName","00000000000", "officeAddress")
```

I don't specify **id** field becouse I don't know it. When I save office (by Anorm) I now **id** and do that:

```
office.id = officeId
```

So. I know that using **null** is non-Scala way. How to avoid using **null** in my case?

**UPDATE #1**

Using **Option**.

Suppose, something like this:

```
case class Office(
   id: Option[Long],
   name: String,
   phone: String,
   address: String
) {
    def this(name: String, phone: String, address: String) = this(
        None, name, phone, address
    )
}
```

And, after saving:

```
office.id = Option(officeId)
```

But what if I need to find something by office id?

```
SomeService.findSomethingByOfficeId(office.id.get)
```

Does it clear? **office.id.get** looks not so good)

**UPDATE #2**

Everyone thanks! I've got new ideas from your answers! Greate thanks!

Comment: is findSomethingByOfficeId(null) a good thing to do? What do you do in the case when there is no officeId and you want to find something by office id.  Option is something that will force you to make decisions about how to handle this case (which is a good thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the `id` field an `Option[Long]`; once you have that, you can use it like this:

```
office.id.map(SomeService.findSomethingByOfficeId)
```

This will do what you want and return `Option[Something]`. If `office.id` is `None`, `map()` won't even invoke the finder method and will immediately return `None`, which is what you want typically.

And if `findSomethingByOfficeId` returns `Option[Something]` (which it should) instead of just `Something` or `null`/exception, use:

```
office.id.flatMap(SomeService.findSomethingByOfficeId)
```

This way, if `office.id` is `None`, it will, again, immediately return `None`; however, if it's `Some(123)`, it will pass that `123` into `findSomethingByOfficeId`; now if the finder returns a `Some(something)` it will return `Some(something)`, if however the finder returns `None`, it will again return `None`.

if `findSomethingByOfficeId` can return `null` and you can't change its source code, wrap any calls to it with `Option(...)`—that will convert `null`s to `None` and wrap any other values in `Some(...)`; if it can throw an exception when it can't find the something, wrap calls to it with `Try(...).toOption` to get the same effect (although this will also convert any unrelated exceptions to `None`, which is probably undesirable, but which you can fix with `recoverWith`).

The general guideline is always avoid `null` and exceptions in Scala code (as you stated); always prefer `Option[T]` with either `map` or `flatMap` chaining, or using the monadic `for` syntactic sugar hiding the use of `map` and `flatMap`.

**Runnable example:**

```
object OptionDemo extends App {
  case class Something(name: String)
  case class Office(id: Option[Long])

  def findSomethingByOfficeId(officeId: Long) = {
    if (officeId == 123) Some(Something("London")) else None
  }

  val office1 = Office(id = None)
  val office2 = Office(id = Some(456))
  val office3 = Office(id = Some(123))

  println(office1.id.flatMap(findSomethingByOfficeId))
  println(office2.id.flatMap(findSomethingByOfficeId))
  println(office3.id.flatMap(findSomethingByOfficeId))
}
```

**Output:**

```
None
None
Some(Something(London))
```

For a great introduction to Scala's rather useful `Option[T]` type, see http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html.

Answer (score 4):

Why not declare the id field as a `Option`?  You should really avoid using null in Scala.  `Option` is preferable since it is type-safe and plays nice with other constructs in the functional paradigm.

Something like (**I haven't tested this code**):

```
case class Office(
   id: Option[Long],
   name: String,
   phone: String,
   address: String
) {
    def this(name: String, phone: String, address: String) = this(
        None, name, phone, address
    )
}
```

Comment: Please, share example which described your idea.

Answer (score 0):

When using `id: Option[Long]` , extract the option value for instance with

```
if (office.id.isDefined) {
  val Some(id) = office.id
  SomeService.findSomethingByOfficeId(id)
}
```

or perhaps for instance

```
office.id match {
  case None => Array()
  case Some(id) => SomeService.findSomethingByOfficeId(id)
}
```

Also you can define case classes and objects as follows,

```
trait OId
case object NoId extends OId
case class Id(value: Long) extends OId

case class Office (
   id: OId = NoId,
   name: String,
   phone: String,
   address: String
)
```

Note that by defaulting `id` for example to `NoId` , there is no need to declare a call to `this`. Then

```
val office = Office (Id(123), "name","phone","addr")
val officeNoId = Office (name = "name",phone="phone",address="addr")
```

If the `id` member is defined last, then there is no need to name the member names,

```
val office = Office ("name","phone","addr")
office: Office = Office(name,phone,addr,NoId)
```

As of invoking (neatly) a method,

```
office.id match {
  case NoId => Array()
  case Id(value) => SomeService.findSomethingByOfficeId(value)
}
```

Comment: You seem to have just reinvented `Option[T]`.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer more strong restriction for object **Id** property:

```
trait Id[+T] {
  class ObjectHasNoIdExcepthion extends Throwable
  def id : T = throw new ObjectHasNoIdExcepthion
}

case class Office(
   name: String,
   phone: String,
   address: String
) extends Id[Long]

object Office {
  def apply(_id : Long, name: String, phone: String, address: String) = 
    new Office(name, phone, address) {
      override def id : Long = _id
    }
}
```

And if I try to get Id for object what is not stored in DB, I get exception and this mean that something wrong in program behavior.

```
val officeWithoutId = 
  Office("officeName","00000000000", "officeAddress")

officeWithoutId.id // Throw exception

// for-comprehension and Try monad can be used
// update office:
for {
  id <- Try { officeWithoutId.id }
  newOffice = officeWithoutId.copy(name = "newOffice")
} yield OfficeDAL.update(id, newOffice)

// find office by id:
for {
  id <- Try { officeWithoutId.id }
} yield OfficeDAL.findById(id)


val officeWithId    = 
  Office(1000L, "officeName","00000000000", "officeAddress")

officeWithId.id // Ok
```

**Pros:**

1) method apply with **id** parameter can be incapsulated in DAL logic

```
private[dal] def apply (_id : Long, name: String, ...
```

2) copy method always create new object with empty **id** (safty if you change data)

3) update method is safety (object not be overridden by default, **id** always need to be specified)

**Cons:**

1) Special serealization/deserealization logic needed for store **id** property (json for webservices, etc)

**P.S.**
this approach is good if you have immutable object (ADT) and store it to DB with id + object version instead object replace.

Comment: Why an exception and not `Option`/`None`?

Comment: Solution with exception is not change type of Id property and it cover problem if you not have id but try to get it (exceptional case, because you expect that id is set but is not). And with Option you can get exception if somebody set id = null (Option is AnyRef).

Comment: Option is good idiom but not compile level, it is runtime feature and unsafe.

Comment: @Erik Allik, I think you do not imagine full picture. Option is good as method output parameter, because you can guaranty returned type. But it is not safety as input parameter for library method `def foo(x : Option[Int])` because somebody can call your method `foo(null)` (or instantiate class Office(id = null, ...)) and it is correct for compiler point of view.

Comment: You should ask a question about this on SO and many people would convince you that you have not fully understood the purpose of Option as an ADT (as opposed to "safety measure").